# Find row corresponding to timestamp in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find the row number corresponding to a timestamp in a pandas dataframe. I think the way I am currently doing it comes up with ambiguous results and does not select the right row:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(freq='d', start='1979-01-01', end='2015-12-30')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=randint(-10, high=20, size=(len(idx),2)), index=idx)
row = abs(df.sum(axis=1)- df.ix['2014-05-30'].sum(axis=1)).values.argmin()
```

when I check my result I get a row number of 77 which gives:

```
df.ix[row]

0    14
1     9
Name: 1979-03-19 00:00:00, dtype: int32
```

This is not the correct date which should have been '2014-05-30'

Is there a more general way of doing this with the pandas timestamp?

Comment: Can you give some short sample of your data (and optimally some code that reproduces it?)

Comment: Why you expect it should be `'2014-05-30'`? The code is summing random integers and searching for the minimum.

Comment: I expect that the number in 'row' should correspond to the time '2014-05-30' because after subtracting the summed value at this time from the summed dataframe the absolute value of the row at the time would equal zero. I think it is not giving the right answer because it is ambiguous so I am looking for a more generic solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [12]: np.random.seed(1234)

In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=randint(-10, high=20, size=(len(idx),2)), index=idx)
```

If you really want the row number

```
In [14]: df.index.get_loc('2014-05-30')
Out[14]: array([12933])

In [15]: df.iloc[12933]
Out[15]: 
0    18
1     8
Name: 2014-05-30 00:00:00, dtype: int64
```

This is partial string indexing, see here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#datetimeindex-partial-string-indexing; in this case its the same as if you specified `df.loc[Timestamp('2014-05-30')]` because its an exact match (e.g. you have daily freq)

```
In [16]: df.loc['2014-05-30']
Out[16]: 
0    18
1     8
Name: 2014-05-30 00:00:00, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for

Comment: Why is the DateIndex different? This doesn't work: `group[group['low'].idxmin()]` but with `.loc` it does. wtf

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie because the result of ``group['low'].idxmin()`` is a scalar and then you are *column* indexing. (not row indexing).